# Writing Enhance Function

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, core-graphics

I'm building an "enhance" function for a crime-fighting project I'm working on. The end goal is to be able to do things like in this documentary video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxq9yj2pVWk

I have it mostly working but I'm getting hung up on the part where you speak into the computer mic and it just does what you want it to do. Here's my function thus far:

```
static const NSInteger kLotsX = MAXFLOAT;
static const NSInteger kLotsY = MAXFLOAT;

- (void)letsEnhance:(UIImageView *)imageView {

    [imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(kLotsX, kLotsY)];

    // Fill in missing pixels / image-data
}
```

(Posted April 1st.)

Comment: There's a pretty good Stanford lecture online about this kind of image processing and enhancement... not sure how directly applicable it is but you can take a look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Comment: Thanks @GeneGoykhman - that was helpful. Anyone else interested in this subject should check out the above link.

Comment: @rmaddy: Your edit removed the crucial hint! (Not sure if April Fool's jokes are on-topic though :)

Comment: @MartinR Duh! I'm being slow this morning. I thought this question was ridiculous but I totally overlooked today's date.